# Change button add to cart color

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, addtocart, less

I've successfully changed it once by this.

[Cascading style sheets (CSS)](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html)

then I want to change it to other colors,
but my new code are not working, the color is still the old one.

I change like this(`_theme.less`):
from`@button-primary__background: @color-orange-red1;`
to  `@button-primary__background: @color-dark-pink1;`

I've **Flush Magento Cache** or **Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache**,
how can I make it change again untill the color I want?

Comment: Are you using any specific theme?

Comment: I created a new theme, which just following the walkthrough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you are in developer mode and that you cleared the cache. After that clear `/pub/static/*` and `var/view_preprocessed`.

Comment: Do I have to do this everytime when I make some changes?
btw,I'm not the local host ,so I think I need to ask someone to change mode for me

Comment: I did what you say and ran the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and It's worked!!